# Parsing error while deploying firebase

Tags: javascript, function, firebase, parsing, command-prompt

Code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref(`/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}/`).onWrite((change,context) =>{
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have a notification to send to ', user_id);

if(!change.after.val()){
return console.log("A Notification has been deleted from the database", notification_id);
}

const fromUser = admin.database().ref('Notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}').once('value');
return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {
const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;
console.log('You have a new notification from : ', from_user_id);

const userQuery = admin.database().ref('UserData/${from_user_id}/name').once('value');
return userQuery.then(userResult => {
const userName = userResult.val();

const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/UserData/${user_id}/TokenID`).once('value');
return deviceToken.then(result => {

const token_id = result.val();

const payload = {
notification: {
title: '${userName}',
body: "You have recieved a new Message",
icon: "default",
click_action : "com.appmaster.akash.messageplus_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
},
data : {
from_user_id : from_user_id,
from_user_name : userName
}
};

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>{
return console.log('This was the notofication Feature');
});
});
});
```

[image: Error]

I have no idea whats causing the error because i don't even understand the errors in command prompt and it doesn't even show where the error is or what it is... Can someone help me out with this please

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code and errors.  It's better to copy the text directly into the question so that it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 0):

You're using template literals, however it looks like you're using standard quotes in some places and not the back tick `. I can also see that you're referencing your user_id variable, however it isn't preceded by the $ symbol with curly braces

template literals need to look like this

```
`string here blah blah with ${variableHere} `
```